# Angular 2 table not refreshing when callback updates collection, timer update refreshes whole collection

Tags: javascript, angular, signalr

I have issue with updating string[] collection from the Observable subscription:

```
heroes:string[] = ['milan'];

// this works fine
  let current = this;
  (function theLoop (i: number) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        current.heroes.push('marta');
        if (--i) {
            theLoop(i);
        }
    }, 10000);
})(10);

let current = this;
// this gets callback every 2s
this.heroesSignalRService.heroeCreated().subscribe((hero) ={
     current.heroes.push(hero);
})
```

Initial collection has only one item and its visible in the UI,
observable callback will add 4 new items before timer adds new item as well.
None of the heroes added by the call back is visible until the timer fires.
After the timer push, all 4 new items added by subscription and 1 hero added
by the timer are visible.

Why is that? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collection refresh has been resolved with ChangeDetectorRef:

```
import {Component, ChangeDetectorRef} from 'angular2/core';

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef)

this.heroesSignalRService.heroeCreated().subscribe((hero) ={
     current.heroes.push(hero);
     current.cdr.detectChanges();
})
```